# new column with row number sql

Tags: sql, window-functions, hana

I have data like below with two columns, I need an output with new column shown below

Input -

```
Name,Date,Value  
Test1,20200901,55  
Test1,20200901,100  
Test1,20200901,150  
Test1,20200805,25  
Test1,20200805,30
```

Row number is based on data from column - Name and Date

Output,

```
Name,Date,Value, row_number  
Test1,20200901,55,1  
Test1,20200901,100,1  
Test1,20200901,150,1  
Test1,20200805,25,2  
Test1,20200805,30,2
```

The query using Partition didn't help

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by Date) as Rank from Table
```

Can someone please help here

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `dense_rank()` - and an `order by` clause:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by Date) as rn from mytable t
```

This gives you a sequential number that starts at `1` on the earliest `date` value increments without gaps everytime `date` changes.

Answer (score 1):

You want `dense_rank()`:

```
select *,
       dense_rank() over (order by Date) as Rank
from Table;
```

There is something suspicious when you are using `partition by` without `order by` (even if the underlying database supports that).